# Ajax send a list as a string instead of just a list

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am using jQuery to gather all the information entered on the webpage, and then using ajax to send this info to my django view. This is the code that takes care of that:

```
var button = $("#serialise");
var JSON_content = $('#JSON_Contents') 

$(button).click(function() {
    var vals = [];

    $("#questions :input").each(function(index) {

    if($(this).attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
        if($(this).prop("checked")) {
            vals.push('on');
        }
        else {
            vals.push('off');
        }
    }else {
        vals.push($(this).val());
    } 
  });

  vals = JSON.stringify(vals);

  var url = window.location.pathname;
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {
        'vals': vals
        },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        //On success
    }
    });
 });
```

The view then receives the info here:

def add_questions(request, review_id = None):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    vals = request.POST.get('vals', None)

    args = {'recieved': 'true'}
    return JsonResponse(args)
```

The problem I am getting, is that the info that is sent, is sent as a string, not as a list. 
So its being sent as `'["Example", "Example"]'` instead of `["Example", "Example"]`.

I assume my `vals = JSON.stringify(vals);` is causing this, however if I remove this, nothing is received by the view.

How do I turn it into the list like I want it to?

Comment: have you tried... not stringifying? jquery handles that for you under the hood.

Comment: @bryan60 returns a NoneType Object

Comment: yes it does... if you tell jquery you're sending json data type it stringifies your post data for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON when you receive it in Django

```
vals = json.loads(vals)
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"` in ajax request.